# Do you need to use Bootstrap's "container" and "row" if your content is to span the whole width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I think the standard of Bootstrap 3 and 4 is

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"> ... </div>
        <div class="col-md-8"> ... </div>   <!-- just add up to 12 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

But what if you have a `div`, `table`, `form`, or any element, that you plan to just let it span the whole width?  Then do you need the `container` or `row` or `col-md-12` at all, for the whole page to display well under the styling rules of Bootstrap 3 and 4?

P.S. if possible, please point to or quote the official Bootstrap docs related to this.

Answer (score 30):

**Short answer**: you *do* need to use `container`, but you *don't* need to use `row`.

You can put elements directly in the `container` or `container-fluid`. You aren't *required* to use the grid (`.row` and `.col-*`), and **the container *alone* can be used as a container of content**. Only use the grid when you need the responsive 12-unit structure.

For example, this is valid Bootstrap...

```
<div class="container">
   <h2>Hello World</h2>
   <p class="lead">Some other content...</p>
</div>
```

From the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)...

> "Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and
> house our grid system."

So, the purpose of `container` is two-fold: 1) to "house the grid system", and 2) to "wrap site contents". However, when you do use the grid (`.row` and `.col-*`), a container is *required* to wrap the `.row`.

Even the [basic starter template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/) utilizes `container` without the grid.

In summary...

- You can use `.container` or `.container-fluid` alone to contain elements and page content.
- *If* you use the grid (`.row` and `.col-*`), `.row` must be inside a `.container` or `.container-fluid`, and `.col-*` must be inside a `.row`.

Comment: I think your answer is more accurate... if I add a wrapper `div` with class `row` and then put `col-md-12` on the `table`, then the table's border is too wide... touching the edge of the page... if i remove the `row` and `col-md-12` stuff then it is perfect

Answer (score 4):

You should add `.container-fluid` to your wrapping div. You should wrap the table, div, or form within a div add the class `.container-fluid` to it.

[The official bootstrap documentation on grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `.container-fluid` class if you want your content to span the full width of the document. Without this class the negative margins of `.row` will cause horizontal scrolling.

You could possibly omit the `container-fluid` *and* `row` but this may cause unexpected results when using other Bootstrap components.

```css
.col-md-4 {
  background: red;
}

.col-md-8 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"> ... </div>
    <div class="col-md-8"> ... </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so just use `.container-fluid` on the `table` or `div` or `form`? Do you need any `row`?

Comment: To do this the Bootstrap way, you would use `.container-fluid > .row > .col-XX-XX`. I don't think you will find anything in the documentation about doing it any other way.

Comment: So even for a div, table, or form to span the whole width, use `.container-fluid > .row > .col-md-12`, that is, always have these 3 layers. So if you put the class `col-md-12` on the `form` or `table`, then you need 2 extra wrappers around it?

Comment: Yes that's right. You can't use columns without rows. You cant use rows without containers. You should use all three together.

Answer (score -2):

Use fluid-container to span entire width of parent.

Comment: There is no fluid-container in Bootstrap